# Groovy - Create an XML element with separated text values

Tags: xml, groovy

How do I create an XML element such as

`<p>This is really <b>important</b>, ok?!</p>`

using the Groovy XML API?

Comment: HTML and XML are not the same thing. Seems you should be looking at Groovy templating https://groovy-lang.org/templating.html

Comment: @ycr: the Groovy templating looks great for cases were I create a complete XML structure from scratch. In my case, I need to insert an XML element in an existing XML file (in the content.xml of an ODT document, to be more precise).

Answer (score 0):

I found that although the Node class only allows adding Nodes, the NodeList also accepts pure String items. And I can obtain a NodeList view of a Node using the children() method.

The solution for me was:

```
def p=new Node(parent, "p")
p.children().add("This is really")
p.children().add(new Node(null,"b",null,"important")
p.children().add("ok?!")
```